# Создание кастомного AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Диалог из приложения Google Maps:

[image: screenshot]

Как реализовать такой AlertDialog, как на скрине ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание  https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android+dialog+custom+view

Answer (score 1):

Для диалога создавай отдельный layout, в нем делай разметку какую тебе нужно, и потом вызывай метод `setView()` для диалога
Хороший пример [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/126-urok-65-dialogi-alertdialog-kastomizatsija)

Answer (score 0):

Есть удобная библиотека для таких целей - [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs).

Кроме того, можно воспользоваться средствами стандартного [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), как  описано в этом вопросе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583828

Comment: Старайтесь не давать голые ссылки, а предоставлять больше информации. В случае библиотеки можно, как минимум, указать название вместо "вот", добавить краткое описание, привести примеры и т. п.